# setState doesn't set object on page with dynamic segments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have problem with getting `state` for component which is loaded by react-router on path with dynamic segment `/item/:id`:

```
var Item = React.createClass({
  mixins: [State],

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {data: {}};
  },

  loadTrackData: function () {
    api.getItemById(this.getParams().id, function (data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.loadTrackData();
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function () {
    this.loadTrackData();
  },

  render: function () {
    console.log(this.state); // empty `data` object
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{this.state.data.title.prop}</h2> // doesn't work
            // but works with 
            // <h2>{this.state.data.title}</h2>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Any of these methods `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` are not called at all!

And render logs empty `data` object as it's just initialized..

Router looks like:

```
var routes = (
  <Route path="/" handler={Index}>
    <Route name="stream" path="/item/:id" handler={Item} />
    <DefaultRoute handler={Dashboard} />
  </Route>
);
```

Comment: Is the API call happening? What value does `this.getParams().id` have?

Comment: API call is not happening because `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` are not called at all!

Comment: Did you run your routes?

Comment: of course I run them.. I just figured out that it doesn't work if I have in render several children in object like `{this.state.data.title.child}` but works with code like `{this.state.data.title}`.

Comment: I've created specific question about that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875906/react-js-object-in-state-with-mutliple-child-properties-and-async-data-does-no