# react.js - Deep Object in state with async data does not work

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, reactjs

I've just figured out that object in React's state that have multiple children cannot be rendered easily.

In my example I have component which speaks with third-party API through AJAX:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {data: {}};
  },

  loadTrackData: function () {
    api.getDataById(1566285, function (data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.loadTrackData();
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{this.state.data.metadata.title}</h2>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The problem is that `{this.state.data.metadata}` renders fine..

But `{this.state.data.metadata.title}` throws error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`!

What is the proper way to deal with such async data?

Comment: Try use `isMounted` method, like this http://jsbin.com/wunaze/1/edit?js

Comment: @Alexander this doesn't help

Comment: have you changed `getInitialState` as in example ?

Comment: @Alexander nope, I didn't notice.. does this mean that I will need to provide children properties that I will use?

Comment: @Alexander do you know some solution (maybe some mixin) that will help to deal with that? Tip from facebook also provides fields by default http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.state.data.metadata` is `undefined` until loading occurs. Accessing any property on `undefined` gives you a `TypeError`. This is not specific to React—it's just how JavaScript object references work.

I suggest you use `{ data: null }` in initial state and return something else from `render` with a condition like `if (!this.state.data)`.

Answer (score 4):

I always like to add the loading spinner or indicator if the page has async operation. I would do this

```
var Component = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {data: null};
  },

  loadTrackData: function () {
    api.getDataById(1566285, function (data) {
      this.setState({data: data});
    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.loadTrackData();
  },

  render: function () {
    var content = this.state.data ? <h2>{this.state.data.metadata.title}</h2> : <LoadingIndicator />;
    return (
      <div>
      {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

with the loading indicator basically it improve the user experience and won't get much of unwanted surprise. u can create your own loading indicator component with lots of choices here http://loading.io/